# Automatically setting a bucket policy in AWS S3. How do I obtain the new buckets name for the script to refer to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This script requires the name of the new bucket in order to be attached. However, it would not receive the name of the new S3 bucket to be referred to in the script. What way can I obtain the name of the new bucket automatically in this script?

```
import json

# Create a bucket policy
bucket_name = 'BUCKET_NAME'
bucket_policy = {
    'Version': '2012-10-17',
    'Statement': [{
        'Sid': 'AddPerm',
        'Effect': 'Allow',
        'Principal': '*',
        'Action': ['s3:GetObject'],
        'Resource': f'arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*'
    }]
}

# Convert the policy from JSON dict to string
bucket_policy = json.dumps(bucket_policy)

# Set the new policy
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy)
```

This is from the boto3 documentation. I need the `bucket_name` to be replaced with the name of the new bucket automatically for this script to attach the policy. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I take that you have a Lambda function triggered by the `s3:CreateObject` event. In this case you can retrieve the bucket name directly from the event. This is what your handler could look like:

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get bucket name from the S3 event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']

    # Create a bucket policy
    bucket_policy = json.dumps({
        'Version': '2012-10-17',
        'Statement': [{
            'Sid': 'AddPerm',
            'Effect': 'Allow',
            'Principal': '*',
            'Action': ['s3:GetObject'],
            'Resource': f"arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*"
        }]
    })

    # Set the new policy
    s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy)
```

If you need more information from the event, refer to the [S3 event message structure documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html).

Comment: If I were to make a lambda function with cloudwatch events, will it be able to receive the new buckets name and be able to execute the policy script? or will this process need to be manual?

Comment: Yes, you can create a CloudWatch Event Rule that listens for the `CreateBucket` event. This can in turn trigger an Amazon Lambda function. The bucket name is included in the event and can be used by the Lambda function.

Comment: what is the variable for the bucket name when the event is triggered?

Comment: You can find the S3 event structure documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

Comment: if the bucket name is included in the event and is able to be used in the lambda function, how do I refer to it?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show what a Lambda function would look like to retrieve the bucket name from the `CreateBucket` event. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I tried out this lambda function but it isnt automatically writing the policy into the bucket. Is there something Im doing wrong

Comment: Do you get any error? Try logging the return value of the put_buckey_policy() call to troubleshoot.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 9, in lambda_handler
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
KeyError: 'Records' is the message I get.

Comment: @notaproatbash that means the event doesn’t have the expected structure. Please log the event using print(event) and have a look at it yourself. Unfortunately I’m not able to help you troubleshoot your whole program through the comment function of Stack Overflow.