# Is there a variable that is used in the event "CreateBucket" which refers to the new bucket's name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Because a new bucket's name will be different every time, my script needs a variable that will refer to each new bucket created's name. Is there a specific variable used for this case?
I am doing this in a Lambda function and have placed a trigger "CreateBucket".

Answer (score 0):

The bucket name is a required parameter whenever you create the bucket via the SDK or [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html)

The response returned will always match the following syntax

```
{
    "Location": "http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/"
}
```

Comment: is there a variable that gets created that refers to the bucket name once it has been created?

Comment: The response contains the one attribute "Location" which is defined as "Specifies the Region where the bucket will be created. If you are creating a bucket on the US East (N. Virginia) Region (us-east-1), you do not need to specify the location." within the documentation. There is no variable returned that contains the name unfortunately.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763858/automatically-setting-a-bucket-policy-in-aws-s3-how-do-i-obtain-the-new-buckets/62764180?noredirect=1#comment111019462_62764180) This forum's comments says that the buckets name is included in the event and can be used in the lambda function. Is there a way I can refer to the new bucket created at least?

Comment: Thats a CloudWatch event that triggers separately, you will pass the bucket name into the create bucket request so if its part of that flow you'll always know the bucket name as you passed it in as parameter :)

Comment: Does this mean that referring to the new bucket's name automatically isnt possible? I am trying to just have this function trigger but with the name from the event passed on to it

Comment: The CloudWatch event is automatic, it won't use the response from the create bucket. If you create an event it will be in the event payload. If you have a script that just creates the S3 bucket you will have the name, as you have to pass the name of your S3 bucket into the function as a parameter :)